# How do I change the hover color to red for Cufon fonts on menu?

Tags: javascript, html, cufon

I have made a menu with Cufon fonts. They are working but I am unable to make HOVER effects on the font. Here is the code I used

`Cufon.replace('#tag', {

   fontFamily: 'ChunkFive',

   color: 'White',

   hover: true,

   textShadow: '1px 1px #555' });`

I wish to use BLUE color when hovering the mouse over a menu link. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Niladri

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cufon.Refresh()` after you load the hover. Everytime you make a modification to an existing cufon element, you need to run refresh to update the element.

Additionally, also try this article - http://galinsimeonov.com/?p=74. Explains the use of Replace and also the FOUC effect that arises with using Cufon.